# Disable Android keyboard for Unity application when an Input Field is clicked

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have manually created my own keyboard prefab in **Unity** and I need to be able to **prevent the default Android keyboard from popping up when the Input Field is clicked.**

Is there any way to do this at all other than not using an Input Field?

The keyboard does NOT use TouchScreenKeyboard, because I need to have more freedom for the behaviour of the buttons.

I am aware of the Hide Mobile Input setting, but I need the entire keyboard disabled, not just the input box.

Comment: You may try Window.SetSoftInputMode (SoftInput.StateAlwaysHidden); - never tested it though

Comment: A simpler approach may be overriding the `onClickListener` of the `View` in your application.